# Issue with exporting osm data manually; is there any command that do it automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, julia, openstreetmap

I'm trying to use export option inside OSM and then use manually select the region options. however, afetr selecting the region and trying to use links like overpass API the downloaded map only has 1KB!?  There's nothing inside of it. I have tried many times and with diffrent boundary sizes and regions.  every time it's just 1KB. What is the issue?

Is there any Python or Julia command that can automatically download a region based on a give coordinate?

[image]

Comment: You could try the OSMnx package in Python. It lets you download a graph, or POIs from a bounding bbox. 
https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.graph

Comment: There is a size limit to Overpass API. You could use extracts, their list is available at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm    Geofabrik is a good server.